# Unparseable date while POST date application/json from PostMan

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, annotations, jersey

I get unparseable date exception. After a lot of searches, I try with Locale.US and Locale.ENGLISH and with dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z" but still the same error. So I try with an annotation from Jackson-dataFormat so I got this with this pattern and try with the pattern "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z" too:

```
@Column(name="date", nullable=false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
private Date date;
```

My dateInString is: "2017-12-23T20:30:15.000Z".
I don't really know where can be the exception.

```
 try {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.US);
        this.date = (Date)formatter.parse(dateInString);            
    }
    catch(ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Maybe this information will help. In my Database, the column is named the date and is DATE type. (I have the choice in phpMyAdmin to choose DATE or DATETIME type).

At the beginning, I thought it was because I forgot the Locale.X parameter but still the exception.

Errors:

```
Caused by: com.owlike.genson.JsonBindingException: Could not parse date 2017-12-23T20:30:15.000Z
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.DefaultConverters$DateConverter.deserialize(DefaultConverters.java:815)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.DefaultConverters$DateConverter.deserialize(DefaultConverters.java:781)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.NullConverter$NullConverterWrapper.deserialize(NullConverter.java:57)
    at com.owlike.genson.reflect.PropertyMutator.deserialize(PropertyMutator.java:30)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-12-23T20:30:15.000Z"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.DefaultConverters$DateConverter.read(DefaultConverters.java:821)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.DefaultConverters$DateConverter.deserialize(DefaultConverters.java:813)
    ... 49 more
```

So I get this errors too but it's because my parsing not work:

```
Caused by: com.owlike.genson.JsonBindingException: Could not deserialize to type class model.SessionActivity
    at com.owlike.genson.Genson.deserialize(Genson.java:442)
    at com.owlike.genson.ext.jaxrs.GensonJsonConverter.readFrom(GensonJsonConverter.java:125)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: com.owlike.genson.JsonBindingException: Could not deserialize to property 'date' of class class model.SessionActivity
    at com.owlike.genson.reflect.PropertyMutator.couldNotDeserialize(PropertyMutator.java:49)
    at com.owlike.genson.reflect.PropertyMutator.deserialize(PropertyMutator.java:32)
    at com.owlike.genson.reflect.BeanDescriptor.deserialize(BeanDescriptor.java:110)
    at com.owlike.genson.reflect.BeanDescriptor.deserialize(BeanDescriptor.java:93)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.BeanViewConverter.deserialize(BeanViewConverter.java:105)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.NullConverter$NullConverterWrapper.deserialize(NullConverter.java:57)
    at com.owlike.genson.Genson.deserialize(Genson.java:440)
    ... 41 more
```

The subject already exist, I read them and try to resolve with these responses but none work actually.

Here is my POST json request:

[image]

Trying with ISO 8601: 2017-12-23T20:30:15.000Z

First, I handle POST request in WebService class:

```
@POST
@Path("/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addSession(SessionActivity sessionActivity) {       
    SessionDAO.add(sessionActivity);
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

It call add() of DAO session:

```
public static void add(SessionActivity sessionActivity){
    try {
        session = SessionUtil.getSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(sessionActivity);        
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println( "ADD sessionActivity non effectué :" );
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then here is my model:

```
@Column(name="date", nullable=false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
    private Date date;

    public SessionActivity(Long id, User user, Date date) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.user = user;
    this.date = date;

    /*
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.US);
        this.date = (Date)formatter.parse(dateInString);            
    }
    catch(ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The format for a json date is ISO 8601: `2017-12-23T20:30:15.000Z`

A json coming with a value like this should parse into a java Date without having to do any conversion. The same the other way round.

By the way, Z at the end means it a Zulu or GMT 0 time. So after the value is parsed into a java Date you can use time zoned methods to get the value for a specific locale.

**EDIT I**

I think there is some issue with the parser you are using. I ran a test using the Genson parser you are using and the same test using Gson, with the same json text, and while Genson couldn't parse the date, Gson parsed it with no problem.

Here is the test, you have to comment the lines you don't want to execute.

Also note I had to annotate the DatedObject class constructor for Genson to find it (`public DatedObject(@JaonParam("date") Date date, JsonParam("user") String user){`)

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.owlike.genson.Genson;
import com.owlike.genson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class JsonParseDate {
    public String json = "{\"date\":\"2017-12-23T20:30:15.000Z\",\"user_fk\":\"1\"}";

    public static void main(String [] args){
        JsonParseDate app = new JsonParseDate();
        app.go();
    }

    private void go(){

        // Comment next two lines to run with Gson (and uncomment the Gson lines)
        // Genson genson = new Genson();
        // DatedObject datedObject = genson.deserialize(json, DatedObject.class);

        // Comment next two lines to run with Genson (and uncomment Genson lines)
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        DatedObject datedObject = gson.fromJson(json, DatedObject.class);
        System.out.println(datedObject.date);

    }

    public static class DatedObject{
        public Date date;
        public String user;

        public DatedObject(Date date, String user){
            this.date = date;
            this.user = user;
        }
    }
}
```

[Ref to Genson user guide](http://owlike.github.io/genson/Documentation/UserGuide/#readwrite-json)

For Gson you can get the jar from maven or add the dependancy to your pom if you are using maven.

Comment: I tried but not work... I'm desperating. Do you want to see the code updated?

Comment: Yes and can you also include a sample of the json you are trying to parse?

Comment: where are you doing the parsing?

Comment: I have 3 packages: one for the service (handling request), the second is the DAO (it uses session and session.save(object), and so on) and the third is the model. Oh! I'm doing the parsing into the model. I should do it in services? Before calling DAO? I don't think so, the @JsonFormat do it automatically normally, using Hibernate.

Comment: I have edited my answer. I tested the same json with Gson insread of Genson (which is the first time I hear of it) and Gson parsed it with no troubble.

Comment: Oh tanks you very much for your time. I will try it as soon as possible and give you some feedback. Sure, I will try with Gson. I took Genson per default because had some problems with Jersey. Keep in touch